# Отдача пользователю php-файла

Tags: php, http

Доброго всем дня.

Имеется такая задача: нужно каждому пользователю отдавать уникальный php скрипт, который генерируется в автоматическом режиме. Можно ли как-то такое организовать или нужно просить пользователя менять расширение после получения файла?

Пытался сделать, отправляя заголовки. Вот код:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$filename = $row['filename'] . '.php';
$source_file = 'wp-block.txt';
$size = filesize($source_file);
$f=fopen($source_file, 'r');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
header("Connection: close"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=". $filename); 
header("Content-Length: ". $size);

echo fread($f, $size);
```

но в итоге при скачивании расширение подменяется на htm. Реально ли сделать такое и как?

Comment: Помог совет Sh4dow, все работает как надо. `"text/plain"` - использовал это.

Comment: @Aferist Кликните, пожалуйста, по галочке слева от ответа @Sh4dow.

Answer (score 1):

С Content-Type поиграйте. Пробуйте "text/plain", "application/x-httpd-php". Должен работать первый.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать Content-Type: text/plain то в броузер выдастся php код.
Если нужно давать именно на скачку файла, при этом задать имя скачанного файла по умолчаниюю, то нужно использовать Content-Type
application/octet-stream или application/x-httpd-php

и

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode("имя_вашего_файла.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если меняется на хтмл, значит отдаёт уже выполненный, и возвращает хтмл страницу, попробуйте тип файла указать другой.

Comment: Там `echo fread($f, $size);`, а не `eval(fread($f, $size));` =) А браузер php не исполняет.

Comment: Я про при обращении к файлу на веб сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, это должно помочь решить проблему:

```
$file = "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/any_file.php";
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
readfile("$file");
```

То есть если есть страничка page.php, которая содержит этот код, то при её посещении будет предложено сохранить файл page.php, содержанием которого будет файл any_file.php.